# How and where are the provisioning script set up in Wordpress?

Tags: docker

How and where are the provisioning script set up in Wordpress? I need to dockerize an application, the issue is after putting the wp_content folder, I noticed the database wasn't provisioned yet (meaning the tables weren't created and the tables weren't populated), so I am thinking there might be some shell script, native scripts and provisioning scripts that didn't run and I am trying to find where they are. Is there a native provisioning system set up already? If so where is it located and how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a native provisioning system set up already?

No.

> I am thinking there might be some shell script, native scripts and provisioning scripts that didn't run

There are none, you have to create those yourself.

> I noticed the database wasn't provisioned yet (meaning the tables weren't created and the tables weren't populated)

WordPress won't install itself, you have to configure and install it yourself, either manually or via a script/provisioner/tool.

---

the closest you'll find to what you're looking for is:

- opening the installer page in the browser by following the classic install instructions https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/#basic-instructions
- or performing those instructions in a script of your own creation via WP CLI commands ( your script will need to download and install WP CLI ) https://wp-cli.org/

There are no system packages or official scripts to do what you are trying to do.

*Also note that the official WordPress docker containers are only official in the sense that Docker themselves created them, the WordPress project was not involved in their creation. The closest WordPress itself has ever gotten is NPM dev tools that use docker for quickly setting up Gutenberg dev environments. These were only intended for local use.*

Having said that, lots of people use containerised WordPress hosts, sometimes at great scale, but the way they do this varies and there is no right or wrong answer, and certainly no officially sanctioned golden path. E.g do you have a database container and a monolithic WordPress container? Or separate PHP worker containers and an Nginx container etc? A dedicated gateway? Standardised PHP/Nginx/MariaDB containers and a bootup script to install WP in a mounted folder with database details? There are lots of options, many I haven't mentioned, with their own tradeoffs to make.